# cannot resolve symbol .getMapAsync

Tags: amazon-web-services, android-fragments

I barely started using the amazon map v2, and it has been working great. Now I am trying to reference the map in my code as explain in the amazon website (https://developer.amazon.com/public/apis/experience/maps/docs-v2/displaying-an-interactive-map-with-the-amazon-maps-api-v2).

The problem is that android studio doesn't recognize the "getMapAsync" method.

Here is my code:

```
    mMapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
            R.id.mapFragment);

    // Call .getMapAsync() and pass it an object that implements
    // the OnMapReadyCallback interface.


    mMapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(AmazonMap amazonMap) {
            // This method is called when the map is ready. The AmazonMap
            // object provided to this method will never be null.

            // Use the map reference to set UI settings and other options.
            amazonMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
            amazonMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);
        }
    });
```

in my build.gradle(project) I have this:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
       jcenter()
       mavenLocal()
    }
}
```

and in my build.gradle(module) I include this:

```
dependencies {
    ...other unrelated dependencies
    compile ('com.amazon.android:amazon-maps-api:2.0')
}
```

thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys I found my mistake. It was quite simple. I needed to use the SupportMapFragment class instead of the MapFragment and change the fragment import to be "android.support.v4.app.Fragment". I am still not sure why I couldn't use the MapFragment as explainned in the website.